# How to access first element of a list of elements after strsplit?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a list of files saved as a list after running
`files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")`

So when I run `files` I have something like the following:

```
AA1131.report.txt
BB1132.reprot.txt
CC0900.report.txt
.
.
.
```

I want to get just the first part of the filename before the `.report.txt` so in R I tried:

```
>files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
>files <- strsplit(files, "\\.")
>files[[1]][1]
[1] "AA1131"
```

I was expecting:

```
[1] "AA1131"
[1] "BB1132"
[1] "CC0900"
```

Or some way to get them and save them as a list so I can use them as ID row names in my tibble for the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to loop over the `list` (from `strsplit`) and extract the first element

```
sapply(files, `[[`, 1)
```

---

The `files[[1]]` extracts only the first `list` element

---

Also, this can be done without an `strsplit`

```
trimws(files, whitespace = "\\..*")
```

or with `sub`

```
sub("\\..*", "", files)
```

Comment: Yup! Both of those worked! Quite clean, I actually forgot about sapply (beena while since I used R). Thanks!

Comment: Usually I get a time limit so I must have forgotten after - my apologies.